# PostgeSQL: create role/user if not exists?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

Is there some way to create a user/role/group in PostgreSQL via SQL only if it does not exist yet? The only solution I have found so far is creating a custom stored procedure, since that supports conditionals. Is there a simpler solution that I have overlooked? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a DO block to only create the role if it doesn't exist, no need for a procedure:

```
do
$$
begin
  if not exists (select * from pg_user where usename = 'new_role') then
     create role new_role password '...';
  end if;
end
$$
;
```

Comment: is there any way to wrap this into a loop for creating several roles? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319704/create-role-if-not-exists-several-users-in-postgres