# CREATE ROLE if not exists (several users) in postgres

Tags: postgresql

[PostgeSQL: create role/user if not exists?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301861/postgesql-create-role-user-if-not-exists)

says

```
do
$$
begin
  if not exists (select * from pg_user where usename = 'new_role') then
     create role new_role password '...';
  end if;
end
$$
;
```

I wonder whether ther is a method inside this SQL to loop this logig through a list of usernames

in pseudo terms it would somethig like ...

```
for username in user1 user2 user3
   if ${username} exists
      create user ${username}
   else
      echo "user exists already"
done
```

Comment: Cursor and iteration over it. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: thx for the tip. It is, however, way beyond my current level of understanding yet. I'll get back to that sort of complexity later and stick to one by one creation for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate your statement into a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_user_if_not_exists(username NAME, pw TEXT) RETURNS integer
    AS $$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM pg_roles  
                   WHERE  rolname = username) THEN

        EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE ROLE "%I" PASSWORD %L', username, pw);
   END IF;
   RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then just have these simple statements

```
SELECT add_user_if_not_exists('user1', 'pw1');
SELECT add_user_if_not_exists('user2', 'pw2');
```

Comment: that looks slick. I am wondering why such a logic is not builtin. The application of IF NOt EXISTS seems somewhat now executed in all consequence (existis for some cases, does not for others) in postgres